# Fragment not added to backstack

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm having trouble with getting Fragments and the backstack to work.

I've got a layout with a FrameLayout for holding various fragments and another fragment:

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/filterableListContainer"
    android:layout_weight="50">
</FrameLayout>


<fragment class="com.facetoe.remotempd.fragments.PlayerBarFragment"
          android:id="@+id/playerBarFragment"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          tools:layout="@layout/player_bar"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

When I start the Activity that uses this layout I add the fragment to the FrameLayout like so:

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);
    if (findViewById(R.id.filterableListContainer) != null) {

        // However, if we're being restored from a previous state,
        // then we don't need to do anything and should return or else
        // we could end up with overlapping fragments.
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            return;
        }

        // Create a new Fragment to be placed in the activity layout
        ArtistListFragment listFragment = new ArtistListFragment();

        // Add the fragment to the 'fragment_container' FrameLayout
        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.filterableListContainer, listFragment);
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        ft.commit();
    } else {
        Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't find filterableListFragment");
    }

}
```

When the user clicks an item, I attempt to replace the fragment with this code:

```
            ArtistAlbumsListFragment fragment = new ArtistAlbumsListFragment(getActivity(), albums);
        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.filterableListContainer, fragment);
        ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        ft.commit();
```

However when I press the back button I get returned to the home screen. Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong?

Comment: you need to add the fragment to the backstack

Comment: Doesn't ft.addToBackStack(null); add the fragment to the backstack?

Comment: It does and it will work

Comment: I'm confused, I have used it in onCreate() and in the code that replaces the fragment? Could you post some example code?

Comment: i can post a example code but that is not relevant here.

Comment: I'm not sure what I'm supposed to do, I have used addToBackStack() in onCreate() and the code that replaces the fragment but it doesn't seem to work. Am I doing it wrong somehow?

Answer (score 3):

Ok I fixed it. When I created the `Activity` in Intellij it created a subclass of `ActionBarActivity`. Removing `ActionBarActivity` and replacing it with `Activity` made the fragments transitions work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Dont add ft.addToBackStack(null) this statement.

ArtistAlbumsListFragment fragment = new ArtistAlbumsListFragment(getActivity(), albums);
            FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.filterableListContainer, fragment);
            ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
            ft.commit();

Comment: You are doing transition between fragments?

Comment: I figured it out, for some reason subclassing ActionBarActivity prevented the fragment from being added to the backstack properly.